# For us really old folks, how do you put those diagrams with moves in a question or answer

Tags: support, pgn-viewer

I think it vaguely has something vaguely to do with something called PGN but not sure what, nor exactly what else we would need to do.

Any youngster out there who can answer then please speak up.

Please with enough details so some really old person can do it.

Comment: You can click on edit on an answer with a diagram and you will see an example of the code needed. Don't forget to leave 4 blank spaces before each line. That's how I learned to post diagrams.

Comment: To obtain the FEN, if you gonna start by an specific position, you have several options on the net. Lichess is where I do it

Comment: Did you tried? Diagrams are usefull when you are a strong player.

Comment: Feel free to ask me anything if you gonna try it. I know from my mom and dad how hard is to learn computer things not having met them at a young age